# How do I send a literal F6/etc. in byobu?

Tags: screen, byobu

In a byobu screen, I ssh'ed into another computer and launched byobu on that computer.  Now, I have byobu within byobu.

How can I send byobu keystrokes (F2, F3, F6, etc) to the inner byobu rather than the outer?  In other words, how do I escape or otherwise transmit these keys to the screen rather than having the outer byobu intercept them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For byobu-within-byobu, you need to know the original, non-f-key bindings for each of the f-key commands.

So for F6, for example, that's really `ctrl-a-d` for detach.

You can then send the detach signal to the inner session using `ctrl-a-a-d`.  And that scales well with the depth of the nested sessions.  So for byobu-within-byobu-within-byobu, you'd use `ctrl-a-a-a-d`.

There is an alternative, which is what I personally use...  You could set a different escape key for the inner byobu.  I typically use `ctrl-a` for the outer one, and `ctrl-b` for the inner one.  In this way, `ctrl-a-d` would detach the outer session, and `ctrl-b-d` would detach the inner session.

Comment: Dustin, how could one configure byobu to set this?

Comment: You can use the `byobu-ctrl-a` helper command to set your escape key, and change it back and forth.

Comment: Is there a list of the commands? I can't find the ctrl-a command for new window. I want to create a new window on the nested session.

Comment: Nevermind, found it. so it's `ctrl-a a c` to create a new window on the nested byobu.

Answer (score 29):

```
Shift-F12                   Toggle on/off Byobu's keybindings
```

Keystrokes will be send to the inner byobu.

Comment: This seems more user friendly than typing `ctrl-a-a-d` (I always got it wrong), since once you type Shift-F12 byobu tells you that its key bindings are disabled. After that, you can for example type `F6` to exit a nested session.

Comment: This is best answer for those who only use f commands.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-A or F12 works with a single byobu, but I'm not sure about a byobu within a byobu.
See:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu