# Change keybinding Shift-F12 in byobu using tmux backend

Tags: shortcut-keys, byobu, tmux

I'm using byobu on my desktop and servers.
To operate in nestet session I'm using Shift-F12, bun when I want to use e.g. htop (F-keys) I need to:

1. add to `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux` the following:
   `bind-key -n C-S-F12 source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux.disable \; display-message "Byobu F-keys: DISABLED"`
   `unbind C-S-F12`
2. edit `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux` to comment out the line:
   `bind-key -n C-S-F12 new-window $BYOBU_PREFIX/lib/byobu/include/mondrian`
   because whithout this I can't bind nothing new to key sequence.
3. edit `share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux.disable` to change the binding
   `bind-key -n S-F12 source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux \; display-message "Byobu F-keys: ENABLED"`
   to bind to
   `C-S-F12`

and it works only once becouse of `source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux.disable` line in `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux`.

Do any one know how to permanetly change `Shift-F12` sequence to `Crtl-Shift-F12` using only `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux` or without editing file outside home dir.

Comment: You might found useful [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271837/how-to-use-byobu-keybindings-in-a-nested-remote-session).